# Conflict between \pagestyle{fancy} and xcolor package

Tags: sectioning, color, fancyhdr

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
% This line causes error message "Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `RED'".
% If this line is removed, or replaced by \pagestyle{empty}, everything goes all right.
% Does that mean the fancy style and xcolor can not go together?  

\begin{document}
\section{\color{red}AAA\hrule} %Removing "\color{red}" outside of \section causes the section number also be colored red, I only want the section text is in red.
section
\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use formatting commands like \color and \hrule in the heading. Or do you want both also in the header and in the table of contents? Use a package like titlesec to define a layout.

Comment: The error message not always are indecipherable verbiage and  sometimes explain  clearly the problem, so always think if it could be a clue for a solution.  In this case,  the problem is that "RED" is undefined, so a solution could be to define "RED". If you define "RED" very different of "red" (in lowercase) at the end of the preamble, e.g, `\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{0,1,0}` (i.e, to produce green color), you will realize instantly the reason for the error and that is not related at all with using "red" in the `\section`.

Comment: @ Thank you all. Heading set from `titlesec`  will change all title format in an article. I think if I can change the format of one certain title only.

Comment: @Fran well that's the same sort of solution as curing a sore toe by cutting off your leg. The error is putting formatting in the argument of `\section` : the fact that it doesn't give an error _message_ in all cases is just unfortunate lack of error checking.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah, I have explained myself terribly.  Obviously, the origin of the  problem is that "RED" is created  unexpectedly, and  this  happens  because "red" exists in `\section`. What I was trying to show  is that the compilation not failed directly because  there is "red"  in the section title, but when LaTeX try to apply "RED" in the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not caused by `fancyhdr` but by the standard LaTeX classes. These define the headers in such a way that `\MakeUppercase` is applied to them. This uppercases everything in the header, including the "red". To show that it isn't `fancyhdr`s fault, remove `fancyhdr` from the `\usepackage` and use `\pagestyle{headings}` instead. It will give the same error.

As @UlrikeFischer said, you shouldn't put the color directly in the section heading. It isn't forbidden, but it is bad practice, as your example shows.

If you don't want to follow Ulrike's advice to use something like `titlesec` there are two ways to solve it. But you are warned that you may still encounter other problems. For example, your `\hrule` will interfere with `fancyhdr`s `\headrule`.

1. Define `RED` to be `red`: `\colorlet{RED}{red}`
2. Remove the uppercasing, by either redefining `\sectionmark` or using `fancyhdr`s `\nouppercase`. This will cause your page headings not to be in uppercase. Of course if it is already all uppercase, you won't notice that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,fancyhdr}
%\colorlet{RED}{red} % not necessary with \nouppercase

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\begin{document}
\section{\color{red}AAA\hrule} %Removing "\color{red}" outside of \section causes the section number also be colored red, I only want the section text is in red.
section
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Do I understand this right -- no headers are given, no error will occur?

Comment: And how to prevent the section title in TOC from being uppercased when `\section{aaa} `

Comment: Section title in the TOC will just be `aaa`, it will not be uppercased.

Comment: "no headers are given, no error will occur?". Yes, the error occurred while formatting the header, because there it had become `\color{RED}` because of the uppercasing. I there is no header this will not happen.